# Stop gradle under condition

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am facing an issue when I try to stop gradle when a condition is not met.
I want when I execute a specific task and a file is not present to throw a `GradleException` but instead it fails to sync with Android Studio.

My code:

```
def mapFile = project.rootProject.file('../../maps.json')
buildConfigField "error", "BUILD_ERROR", '"maps.json is missing"'
if(!mapFile.exists()) throw new GradleException("File does not exist")
```

I have found this solution(don't really like it) with code:

```
buildConfigField "error", "BUILD_ERROR", '"maps.json is missing"'
```

so the BuildConfig will generate an error variable and the gradle will stop. Any other options of actually throwing an exception and the sync does not fail?

Comment: Are you trying to stop the build running in Execution phase, or during Configuration?  I suspect you're trying to stop it during Configuration phase, which may be why you're seeing the error syncing to IntelliJ...  Can you come up with a small example build file that fails to sync?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that @tim_yates is right. If you only want the task to fail, you need to use a `doFirst` closure. If you just use the task configuration closure, the task configuration will fail and also each Gradle invocation, even the one Android Studio uses to fetch information. This results in a failed 'sync'.

Comment: Actually I do not care what happens in Android Studio but I just added this work around because of CI. When I will build in CI and it does not have the file then crash it/stop it whatever to fail the build.

Answer (score 3):

To let the task fail and not the whole build, you must raise the exception at task execution:

```
task myTask(type: MyType) {
    def mapFile = project.rootProject.file('../../maps.json')
    // do some configuration ...
    doFirst {
        if(!mapFile.exists()) throw new GradleException("File does not exist")
    }
}
```